# CSS3 maintain final animation keyframe if below 100% progress

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I am animating a div using a zoom in effect, when scrolling to it.

First I am setting the div to opacity 0 because I want it hidden until I scroll to it:

```
div {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

In my JS, when the element enters the viewport/screen, I am adding class `zoomIn` to it.

```
@keyframes zoomIn {
     0% {
         opacity: 0;
         transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);

     }
     50% {
         opacity: 1;
     }
 }

 .zoomIn {
     animation-name: zoomIn;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 }
```

The issue:

After the animation finishes, the div goes back to opacity 0.

A solution I found:

```
@keyframes zoomIn {
     0% {
         opacity: 0;
         transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);

     }
     50% {
         opacity: 1;
     }
     100% {
         opacity: 1;
     }
 }
```

I am adding 100% to keyframes to maintain the opacity 1.

Is there a way to accomplish this without adding `100%` to the keyframe? Can I just preserve the opacity at 50%?

**Note:** I must use keyframe 50%. The above animation is a simplified example. The goal is to find out how to maintain the state in the last keyframe whether it's 50% or any other value below 100%.

Comment: Why do you set the `opacity(1)` at `50%` exactly? Wouldn't it be simpler to set it to be `opacity(1)` at `100%` and halve the animation's duration?

Comment: From the [CSSDraft Spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations/#keyframes): _If a 100% or to keyframe is not specified, then the user agent constructs a 100% keyframe using the computed values of the properties being animated._ Basically, I think this is saying that since you don't provide a `100%` keyframe animation stop, it will use the computed value of the property - which is `0`. Curious, why don't you use 100% instead of 50%?

Comment: @Kaiido i added a simplified example. The goal is to find out how to maintain the state in the last keyframe whether it's 50% or any other value below 100%.

Comment: @disinfor my example is simplified. The goal is to find out how to maintain the state in the last keyframe whether it's 50% or any other value below 100%.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Why do you need to maintain the state at this position? Why can't you set it to 100% and change the duration? Do you know you can have multiple animations running on the same element simultaneously? SO nothing should prevent you from having your animation ends correctly at 100%.

Comment: @Kaiido i am using a css library with hundreds of animations. Most of them have the 50% keyframe. I cannot modify the css library. I need to figure out how to preserve whatever is at 50%.

Comment: Give us a more robust example of what you're actually working with. As of now, Kaiido's question (why not just set 100% with a faster duration) and the CSS Spec give you the reasons why your property isn't maintaining state.

Comment: @CyberJ can you pass us also the link for the library?

Comment: @Lucie https://animate.style/